# How can I write the result to the csv?

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader, streamwriter

I want to ping the hostnames that are in the csv and write the result in the next column, but I'm little bit lost how to do it?

This the error I get:Error  CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'StreamReader'

And the only thing I can do is write to the console what is in the csv.

```
    string filePath = @"c:\hostnames.csv";
    var reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    List<string> hostnames = new List<string>();
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(',');
        hostnames.Add(values[0]);
        hostnames.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }

    List<string> goodPing = new List<string>();
    foreach (string singleComputer in hostnames)
    {
        PingReply pingresult = ping.Send(singleComputer);

        if (pingresult.Status.ToString() == "Success")
        {
            goodPing.Add(singleComputer);
        }
    }
        var csv = new StringBuilder();
        var first = reader[0].ToString();   
        var newLine = string.Format("{0}");
        csv.AppendLine(newLine);
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, csv.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: what error you are getting? and I see there is an extra { .. please update your post and make it clear what you tried what error you get, so people can help you better

Comment: I updated the problem.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your hostnames.csv file looks like now and what you want it to look like when you are done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what error you are getting is but one issue I noticed is you are not providing a variable to string.Format which I think it is useless at there..

Example hostnames.csv is something like this I assume:

```
www.google.com,www.somebadu-rlwhichcannot..com,www.stackoverflow.com
```

---

```
        var filePath = @"c:\test\hostnames.csv"; // change it to your source
        var filePathOutput = @"c:\test\hostnamesOutput.csv"; // use separate output file so you would not overwrite your source..
        var ping = new Ping();
        var hostNames = new List<string>();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                hostNames = line.Split(',').ToList();
            }
        }

        var goodPing = new List<string>();

        foreach (var singleComputer in hostNames)
            try
            {
                var pingResult = ping.Send(singleComputer);
                if (pingResult.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    goodPing.Add(singleComputer);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // host was not in a correct format or any other exception thrown....
                // do whatever error handling you want, logging etc...
            }

        var csv = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var hostname in hostNames)
        {
            var resultText = goodPing.Contains(hostname) ? "Success" : "Failed";
            var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1}", hostname, resultText);
            csv.AppendLine(newLine);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(filePathOutput, csv.ToString());
```

I didn't try on IDE but it should be doing what you are trying to do. Seems you copy pasted that code from somewhere and tried to manipulate it without understanding. I would suggest to make sure you understand it line by line why it is used, how it is used before you start using it. Otherwise you will always need someone to write the code for you!

Output will be (in excel):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of what I think you are trying to do.

Example hostheaders.csv before code runs

```
www.google.com
www.stackoverflow.com
www.fakewebsitehere.com
```

Updated code

```
string filePath = @"c:\hostnames.csv";
List<string> results = new List<string>();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    Ping ping = new Ping();

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(',');
        var hostname = values[0];
        Console.WriteLine(hostname);

        PingReply pingresult = ping.Send(hostname);

        results.Add($"{line},{pingresult.Status.ToString()}");
    }
}

File.WriteAllLines(filePath, results);
```

hostheaders.csv after code runs

```
www.google.com,Success
www.stackoverflow.com,Success
www.fakewebsitehere.com,TimedOut
```